# Binary search tree delete

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Delete function is not working in this BST Tree.
Problem 1 it does not make the deleted node null as i have given in the code and second it goes infinite in else condition.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct bstnode{
bstnode *lchild;
int data;
bstnode *rchild;    
};

void creatbst(bstnode *&T,int k){
    if(T=='\0'){
        T=new(bstnode);
        T->data=k;
        T->lchild='\0';
        T->rchild='\0';
    }
    else if(k<T->data){
        creatbst(T->lchild,k);
    }
    else if(k>T->data){
        creatbst(T->rchild,k);
    }
}

bstnode *searchbst(bstnode *T,int k){
    if(T=='\0')
    return ('\0');
    else{

     if(k<T->data)
return searchbst(T->lchild,k);  

    else if(k>T->data)
    return searchbst(T->rchild,k);  

    else
        return T;
    }
}

int nmax(bstnode *T){
    while(T->rchild!='\0'){
        T=T->rchild;
    }
    return (T->data);
}
int nmin(bstnode *T){
    while(T->lchild !='\0'){
        T=T->lchild;
    }
    return (T->data);
}
void printleaf(bstnode *T){
    if(T=='\0'){
    return; 
    }
    else if((T->rchild=='\0')&&(T->lchild=='\0'))
    cout<<T->data<<endl;
    else{
        printleaf(T->lchild);
        printleaf(T->rchild);
    }
}
void printnleaf(bstnode *T){
    if(T=='\0'){
        return;
    }
    else if(T->rchild!='\0' || T->lchild!='\0')
    {cout<<T->data<<endl;;
    printnleaf(T->lchild);
    printnleaf(T->rchild);}
    else{
    return;
    }
}

void ldelete(bstnode *T,int x){
    int y;
    T=searchbst(T,x);

    if((T->lchild=='\0')&&(T->rchild=='\0'))
    T='\0';
    else{
        y=nmax(T->lchild);
        T->data=y;
        ldelete(T,y);
    }
}



int main(){
    bstnode *T;
    bstnode *D;
    T='\0';
    creatbst(T,36);
    creatbst(T,20);
    creatbst(T,75);
    creatbst(T,42);
    creatbst(T,8);
    creatbst(T,31);
    creatbst(T,25);
    creatbst(T,3);
    creatbst(T,80);

    ldelete(T,20);
    printleaf(T);
    printnleaf(T);
    return 0;

}
/*delete function is not working*/
```

Comment: _not working_ isn't much to go on. Can you explain what's happening and what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference to the node T:

```
void ldelete(bstnode*&T,int x){
    int y;
    T=searchbst(T,x);

    if((T->lchild=='\0')&&(T->rchild=='\0'))
    T='\0';
    else{
        y=nmax(T->lchild);
        T->data=y;
        ldelete(T,y);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the `T` node is just updated locally in the function.
[I'm not convinced that this is sufficient to completely fix your code, but it should fix the immediate problem].

In other comments: don't use `'\0'` to indicate a null pointer value. It is a NUL charactger, not a NULL pointer value, they are quite different - the compiler may well accept both as the same, but for the reader it makes a big difference.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Of course. I tend to not use this construct much, and I keep getting it wrong when using it in replies (and the few times I use it in my own code just to be consistent)... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You modify `T`, but `T` is a local variable. You have to pass `T` as a reference if you want to change the varable passed by the caller. Just as you do in `createbst`.

And by the way, you are leaking memory.